# Checking whether an element in inside an array, using D?

Tags: arrays, d

We have a `char` and a `char[]`.

What would be the most efficient (or, failing that, just simplest) way of finding out whether the `char` is located inside of `char[]`?

The language used is D.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the character array sorted?

Comment: No. Its contents are unknown, and length greater than one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it's not sorted, the only thing you can do is loop through and check each element, breaking or returning if a match is found.

```
char char1 = ...;
char[] chars = ...;

foreach(char char2; charArray)
  if (char2==char1)
      return true;
return false;
```

forgive me if that doesn't compile - i'm rusty with d.